Create dummy for missing values for variable in Python
I have the following dataframe in:
  a
1 3
2 2
3 Nan
4 3
5 Nan

I need to recode this column so it looks like this:
  df_miss_a
1 0
2 0
3 1
4 0
5 1

I've tried:
df_miss_a = np.where(df['a'] == 'Nan', 1, 0)

and
df_miss_a = np.where(df['a'] == Nan, 1, 0)

The above outputs only 0s.
The format of the output is unimportant.

@mkrieger1 amended per your suggestions.

Does this answer your question? Pandas Replace NaN with blank/empty string

@ti7 It doesn't, because the solutions suggested there (using replace or fillna) only solve part of OP's problem; namely replacing all values that are NaN. However, OP also wants to replace all values that are not NaN.

If you have NaNs in your column you can use pd.Series.isna():
df_miss_a = df["a"].isna().astype(int)
print(df_miss_a)

Prints:
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    1
Name: a, dtype: int64


pd.Series.fillna(0) is simpler and more obvious

@DeusXMachina pd.Series.fillna(0) would not work: (1) It sets NaN to 0 rather than 1, as required by OP. Of course, this could easily be mitigated by pd.Series.fillna(1); however, this would leave the 2nd problem: (2) OP wants all values that are not NaN to be set to 0. Your solution with fillna() would simply leave them alone, so you would require an extra step, while Andrej Kesely's answer solves both issues at once.

Ah, thanks for the clarification. I read it too fast.
